# Batch file that includes count variable in the command being run

Tags: windows, batch-file

I'm trying to build a batch file to run a certain number of times based on a count, and inserting the count number into a command like parameter like this:

```
set count=5
dountil count=26
count=count+1
c:\path\file.exe someparamenters fileCOUNT someotherparameters fileCOUNT
```

The command would run a command including filenames that count up like this:

```
c:\path\file.exe someparamenters file5 someotherparameters file5  
c:\path\file.exe someparamenters file6 someotherparameters file6  
c:\path\file.exe someparamenters file7 someotherparameters file7  
etc etc
```

I can't figure out how to run the command while inserting the count into the command.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
set count=5
set dountil=26
for /L %%e in (%count%,1,%dountil%) do c:\path\file.exe someparamenters file%%e someotherparameters file%%e
```

See `for /?` from the prompt or endless examples on SO for documentation.

Comment: Wow that was easy, thanks! I've never used a method like that to count, and I was using %e not %%e, what's the difference?

Comment: `metavariables` (the control variable in a `for` loop) need a double `%` within a batch file, but a single `%` if the `for` is executed directly from the prompt.